# how to ignore a collider using rayast in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mask, layer, raycasting, collider

I have 2 game objects, game object "A" and game object "B". Game object "B" is inside the collider of game object "A". i want to  click on game object "B". How to make the raycast pass through the Gameobject "A" 's collider

Comment: Have it on a different layer tag. And look for the one you want

Comment: I agree with @BugFinder, if you are certain of the object being inside a collider when you need to raycast, you should be able to work out the layer tags that you would need.

Comment: You could set Object A's layer to `IgnoreRaycast`, and A will be ignored by all raycasts.  If you need to raycast A elsewhere, set it on a different layer than B and use the layermask parameter when doing the raycast.